# Do not allow empty strings in GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

We have a field which expects a non-nullable string with type `String!` however Apollo will except this field if it is an empty string or string with just empty spaces.

We have tried using scalar type `NonEmptyString` however no luck.

Is there a way to add non-empty string type to our Apollo Server graphql schema?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this should be possibe using the custom scalar

```
export const NonEmptyString = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'NonEmptyString',
  description: 'Non empty string',
  serialize: (value: unknown): string => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || value === '') { // or any custom validation
      throw new Error('Wrong value type');
    }

    return value
  },
  parseValue: (value: unknown): string => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || value === '') {
      throw new Error('Wrong value type');
    }

    return value
  },
});
```